# How to set/apply default ES to compile to in tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript

My TypeScript compiles down to (probably) ES5, which was the original default.

I can compile down to much more modern JavaScript such as ES2019 with

```
tsc main.js -t 'ES2019'
```

But how can I set ES2019 as the default on my system for that project?

I created a tsconfig.json file and changed it to have:

```
$ cat tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // "incremental": true,
    "target": 'ES2019',
    "module": "commonjs",  
    ...
```

but it didn't seem to take effect - I use `tsc main` and I still get older JavaScript unless I specify the option directly at the command line with `tsc main -t 'ES2019'`

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Answer (score 3):

The config file was correct.

*The fact that I was passing the source file as a param was the issue.*

This seemed non-intuitive to me.

If you use `tsc` with no params it **does** uses the `tsconfig.json` file and respects and uses the `target` ES version.

However if you pass the file to compile as a param for `tsc` at the command line, it does **not** use the `tsconfig.json` file and also when I tried to use it with -p I got an error:

```
$ tsc main.ts -p tsconfig.json                                                                                                                                                           
error TS5042: Option 'project' cannot be mixed with source files on a command line.
```

---

So tsc with **no** param **does** use the `tsconfig` file and the ES version within it.

Answer (score 0):

Target needs to be within the `compilerOptions` section.

Comment: Thanks.  I added info to the question to show that is where it is.